# How can I get the name of the most recent snapshot for an RDS DB instance using the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

Using the AWS CLI, how can I get the most recent snapshot for a particular DB instance?

I can get them through the GUI easily but I'd like to automate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`aws rds describe-db-snapshots`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-snapshots.html) CLI command to get a list of DB snapshots, and then run a local query using `--query` to get the latest DB snapshot using the `SnapshotCreateTime` field.

> SnapshotCreateTime -> (timestamp)
>
> Specifies when the snapshot was taken in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). Changes for the copy when the snapshot is copied.

Something like this:

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots \
    --db-instance-identifier your-id \
    --query "sort_by(DBSnapshots, &SnapshotCreateTime)[-1].{id:DBSnapshotIdentifier,time:SnapshotCreateTime}"
```

Note that this query sorts snapshots by their ascending SnapshotCreateTime and then simply takes the last one in the list (as dictated by [-1]), which will be the one that was last created.

[Added] if you're looking for snapshots of Aurora DB clusters then you'd have to use `describe-db-cluster-snapshots` in place of `describe-db-snapshots`, but otherwise the process is similar: use `DBClusterSnapshots` and `DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier` (in place of `DBSnapshots` and `DBSnapshotIdentifier`).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTG1Q.jpg is what I'm seeing in Amazon but when I do `aws rds describe-db-snapshots` I get `{ "DBSnapshots": [] }` back. Shouldn't I get back all the snapshots I have?

Comment: Are you running the awscli against the correct region? I'd expect to see all automated (system) and manual snapshots.

Comment: @jarmond - Turns out I needed to needed to do `describe-db-cluster-snapshots` instead of `describe-db-snapshots`.